# How do I access an object, knowing only its memory address and not a variable that refers to it?

Tags: python, regex, memory

I am trying to debug a script and there is a certain regular expression that I want to check. (the regex is passed into my program as a parameter from another script, so I cannot manually just look up the regex.) During the debugging process I notice that the regex in question is loaded into memory, so I see something like

```
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x000000000DB6E5D0>
```

I want to access that regex object so I can see exactly what it is doing, but I cannot seem to find a way to access memory in python. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Everything in a script is loaded into memory, you're making a meaningless distinction. Your question should be "How do I access an object, knowing only its memory address and not a variable that refers to it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to print the regex object directly, along these lines:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('my regex')
>>> print p
_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02274380
```

You can simply refer to the pattern as `p.pattern`:

```
>>> p.pattern
'my regex'
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the pattern the regular expression was compiled with from the `pattern` attribute:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r'^(.*)$')
>>> r = re.compile(r'^(.*)$')
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7fa384ce5918>
>>> r.pattern
'^(.*)$'
```